# Uploading file to specific folder in Google Drive

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have two methods, one for creating file and uploading it to root folder to Google drive and second to just to create a folder to Google drive.

Is there possibility to somehow connect these two and upload file to that newly created folder?

I have read google documentation but I can't figure out the place, where I can alter to which folder this file goes

To create a file:

```
    private Task<Void> createFileIntentSender(DriveContents driveContents, File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");

        // Get an output stream for the contents.
        OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();

        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            fis.read(bytesArray); //read file into bytes[]
            fis.close();
            outputStream.write(bytesArray);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setTitle(windowName.getText().toString())
                .setMimeType("application/vnd.ms-excel")
                .setStarred(true)
                .build();

        // Set up options to configure and display the create file activity.
        CreateFileActivityOptions createFileActivityOptions =
                new CreateFileActivityOptions.Builder()
                        .setInitialMetadata(changeSet)
                        .setInitialDriveContents(driveContents)
                        .build();

        return mDriveClient
                .newCreateFileActivityIntentSender(createFileActivityOptions)
                .continueWith(
                        new Continuation<IntentSender, Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public Void then(@NonNull Task<IntentSender> task) throws Exception {
                                startIntentSenderForResult(task.getResult(), REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                                return null;
                            }
                        });
    }
```

To create folder:

```
    private void createFolder() {
        mDriveResourceClient.getRootFolder()
                .continueWithTask(task -> {
                    DriveFolder parentFolder = task.getResult();
                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setTitle("Folder1")
                            .setMimeType(DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE)
                            .setStarred(true)
                            .build();
                    return mDriveResourceClient.createFolder(parentFolder, changeSet);
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, e -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create file", e);
                    finish();
                });
    }
```

Comment: `return mDriveResourceClient.createFolder(parentFolder, changeSet);` What does that return? And what are you doing with the return value?

Comment: `createFileIntentSender(DriveContents driveContents, ` Nobody can see how you call this function. Especially one would like to know the value of driveContents.

Comment: Hello, did your issue get solved? Remember that if you want to mark your question as solved you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) whatever answer provided a solution to your problem. If that's not the case and your issue is not solved, please consider explaining why that's not the case so that this community can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to first upload your file to the `root` folder. You can upload your file directly to your desired folder.

First, you would need to [create the folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#create_a_folder) you want to upload your file to. This method returns a [File resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) (`files` and `folders` are [basically the same](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-files#types) in Drive, the main differences being that `folders` only contain metadata and have MIME type `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`).

Second, you have to [upload your file directly to the created folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#insert_a_file_in_a_folder). To do this, when making the call, you have to specify the `folder ID` (which you can get from the response of previous step) in the `parents` property of the file (check this to see [all the properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create#request-body) you can specify in your file).

I hope this is of any help to you.

Comment: Took time to sort out all my deprecated classes but got it working. Thanks for pointing these things.